# Android `slack://share-file` to channel

Tags: android, slack

How to use the Slack [deep link sharing API](https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking#share_a_file) to preselect the channel in the sharing dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the documentation:

 https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking#client__supported-uris__open-a-channel

> slack://channel?team={TEAM_ID}&id={CHANNEL_ID}

Comment: This will open a channel, but I need to share a file to that channel.